# ExtJS and ASP.Net Web API file upload error

Tags: c#, extjs, asp.net-web-api

I posted a question yesterday. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058148/redirecting-to-api-url-while-submitting-extjs-form) is the link but I didn't get any response. I have made few changes in the code and I am re-submitting the code with the error I get. I am using ExtJS MVC approach to upload a file to the server. On the server end I have ASP.Net Web API's for handling the server side functionality. I have an ExtJS form inside a window that I am using to upload file. My controller on the server side recieves the file properly and also returns the following JSON:

```
{"$id":"1","success":true,"result":"Uploaded Successfully.","error":null}
```

The issue is that the upload does not finish. It keeps on showing "Please wait..." message. Looking into the Chrome developer tool I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Here is the complete code of the view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.AddCountry', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.addcountry',
    closable: true,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    modal: true,
    height: '28%',
    width: '45%',
    layout: 'fit',
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.items = [{
            xtype: 'form',            
            bodyPadding: '5 5 0',
            itemId: 'addCountryForm',
            frame: false,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' },//Removing this also doesn't work.
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                maxLength: 25,
                enforceMaxLength: true,
                allowBlank: false,
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Description',
                maxLength: 100,
                enforceMaxLength: true,
                allowBlank: false,
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'flagImage',
                fieldLabel: 'Flag',
                buttonText: 'Select Image...',
                flex: 1
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Save',
                itemId: 'btnAddCountry'
            }, {
                text: 'Cancel',
                itemId: 'btnCancelAddingCountry'
            }]
        }];
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Controller code:

```
AddNewCountry: function (button) {
        var form = button.up('form').getForm();
        form.submit({
            url: 'localhost/myapp/api/addcountry',
            waitMsg: 'Please wait...',
            success: function (f, o) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', o.result.result);
            },
            failure: function (f, o) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', o.result.error);
            }
        });
},
```

This is what I have written on the server side:

```
public UploadResult AddNewCountry()
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                string fileName = httpRequest.Files[0].FileName;//I am able to get this
            }
            UploadResult objResult = new UploadResult();
            objResult.success = true;
            objResult.result = "Uploaded Successfully.";
            return objResult;
        }

public class UploadResult
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public string result { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }
```

I am sure there has to be something in the Form's config but I am unable to find. Can someone point out the issue here?